# How To Create pk8 and pem files programmically?

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to create pem and pk8 files by my app itself using java programmically?

Answer (score 0):

Bouncycastle can presumably handle any cases you would need.  https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/bc3b92f1f0e78b82e2584c5fb4b226a13e7f8b3b/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PrivateKeyFactory.java

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/bc3b92f1f0e78b82e2584c5fb4b226a13e7f8b3b/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMParser.java

OkHttp internally uses such functionality here https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls to generate certificates for testing. It is split out into a separate project https://github.com/cashapp/certifikit, but not as complete and battle tested as Bouncycastle.